# Why does my Paperclip validates_attachment_presence test fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, paperclip-validation

In my Rails 3.2.2 project, I have the following:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  default_scope order: :title

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, :use => :slugged
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :title, :uniqueness => {:scope => :album_id}
  validates :file, :attachment_presence => true

  has_attached_file :file, :path => (Rails.root + "photos/:id/:style/:filename").to_s,
                           :url => "/photos/:style/:id",
                           :styles => { :small => "450x450>"}
end

class PhotoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should belong_to(:album)

  should validate_presence_of(:title)
  should have_attached_file(:file)
  should validate_attachment_presence(:file)
end
```

The 'should validate_attachment_presence(:file)' test always flunks, but I can't figure out why.  I have other unit tests with required attachments that test out fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run paperclips internal tests against your setup? To ensure that it's not something coming from paperclip it self?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I'm trying to use the Paperclip matchers, as described at http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers#validate_attachment_presence-instance_method

Comment: Firstly, you should open the paperclip gem in your terminal: `cd to/where/paperclip/is/located` and then run `bundle install` to install dependencies. You then run `rake` or `rake test` (can't remember which) to test paperclip against your system, to see if there is something wrong with paperclip setup on your system.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Rails 3.2.3, Paperclip 3.0.2 and on Ruby 1.9.3-p125. The `should validate_attachment_presence(:file)` always fails. As suggested by @Ekampp I ran the Paperclip tests, but they finished without any errors.

Comment: Hmm.. The I have no idea as to the problem. I have had paperclip running fine on a 3.2.1 app, maybe there was something that changed from 3.2.1 to 3.2.2?

Comment: This is a paperclip bug and can be referenced below: Visit <https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1194>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the problem disappeared after I upgraded to Paperclip 3.0.3 - seems like the bug is now fixed.